# Powershell replace operator is bringing across array artifacts

Tags: powershell, date, replace, format

I need to get a date from a cell in a CSV file, then remove the '20' from the year.

[image]

I have the below code:

```
$rateID="C:\Folder\Path\RateIDTable.csv"
$date = Import-CSV $rateid | select -first 1 -Property date
$date = $date -replace '[20]',''
write-output $date
```

Output looks like this though:

[image]

What I need is '17/01/18' but it adds the whole variable and removes the zero that I need.

Any tips on this one?

Thanks!

Comment: `Import-CSV $rateid | select -first 1 -ExpandProperty date` or `(Import-CSV $rateid)[0].date` Your regex will remove all 2 and 0 from the string

Comment: Dammit, I just made a messy resolution! The first one works beautifully and will be getting used. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your $date object, format it as such:

```
$date = $date.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

Adding more clarification since my answer did not seem to work for you.  I assumed a few things, that I can see did not work for you.

```
$date1 = [datetime]::Now
$date2 = [datetime]::Parse("01/18/2018")
$mydate = "01/19/2018"
$date3 = [datetime]::Parse($mydate)

$date1.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
$date2.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
$date3.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

Your `$date` was a string, not a Date, so yes, to use `ToString`, it would need to be a DateTime object which you can see a few ways to create above.  Hope this helps you in future efforts.

Note, you may need to change the strings depending on your locale so they parse correctly, but hopefully the above makes sense...

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error "Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1" ". I only have Version 2 on my crappy work PC if that makes a difference? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either you convert the "string date" to a [datetime object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-5.1) and format it accordingly or you change the [regex pattern](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.11.powershell.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you use in your `-replace` operator like this

```
$date = $date -replace '/20','/'
```

The square brackets in regex define a [charachter class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html). So with **'[20]'** the regex matches **ALL** two's and **ALL** zero's in the string.

Comment: No luck. Tried to used the [datetime] accelerator, but get errors wherever I use it. I might write the variable to a txt file, then pull it back out as a string. The [ ] tip was useful though! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out. bit of a messy way to do it, but here is my code:

```
$rateID="C:\Folder\Path\RateIDTable.csv"
$datestr="C:\folder\path\fdate.txt"
$date = Import-CSV $rateid | select -first 1 -Property date 
$fdate = $date | foreach-object {$_.date} | set-content $datestr
$fdate = (get-content $datestr) -replace ('20','')
write-output $fdate
```

And my output is this:
17/01/18

Thanks to all those who helped!

Comment: Used Matt's reslolution posted as a comment to my original post. Thanks Matt!

Comment: That's gonna mess up with day dates like 20/01/2018 or 20/02/2018 and so on. I posted a regex pattern that should work for most of the time.  ;-)

Comment: Oh I see! You are completely correct. Hopefully I remember to fix this when I get back to work after leave haha! Thanks